# Show post tags in a widget

Tags: widgets, tags

I'm looking to show the tags of a post within a widget. I know this is hard because it's outside of the loop, but has it been done, is there one available?

Answer (score 3):

Tags can be shown outside the **Post loop** using the global functions.

Step 1 : Get a [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) (this solved many problems)

Step 2 : Place the Code `<?php the_tags(); ?>` in widget and Save.

Check [Tags Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) to tweak display order.

All done just rock and roll.

Comment: Nice! This worked for me. Tags in Widget.

Answer (score 2):

Its not very hard actually, WordPress supports multiple loops and query's.

The best way to create a secondary (or more) loop is to make an instance of [`WP Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Using that you can make a simple query that gets the posts tags using [`wp_get_post_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)

Then you would throw the code into a [widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).